# Transform an object with an array into an array

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the following data structure:

```js
const data = {
  "firstName": "A",
  "lastName": "B",
  "address": [{
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Paris"
  },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Rome"
    }
  ],
};
```

Using Ramda I would like to transforms it into:

```js
const result = [
  {
    "firstName": "A",
    "lastName": "B",
    "address": {
      "country": "France",
      "city": "Paris"
    },
  },
  {
    "firstName": "A",
    "lastName": "B",
    "address": {
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Rome"
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: This question (or rather one of its answers) is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422655).  @Dharman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `converge` function to fork the prop `address` and then join it with the main object for each address in the list:

```js
/**
 * R.pick could be replaced with R.omit
 * to let you black list properties:
 * R.omit(['address']); https://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit
**/
const createByAddress = R.converge(R.map, [
  R.pipe(R.pick(['firstName', 'lastName']), R.flip(R.assoc('address'))),
  R.prop('address'),
]);

const data = {
  "firstName": "A",
  "lastName": "B",
  "address": [{
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Paris"
    },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Rome"
    }
  ],
};

console.log(createByAddress(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

My question is why "with Ramda"?  I'm a founder of Ramda and a big fan, but it's just a tool, and unless this is a learning exercise for Ramda, it doesn't seem like there is any need to use it for this problem.

I would do it like this, using modern JS techniques:

```js
const transform = ({address, ...rest}) => 
  address .map (a => ({...rest, address: a}))

const data = {firstName: "A", lastName: "B", address: [{country: "France", city: "Paris"}, {country: "Italy", city: "Rome"}]}

console .log (
  transform (data)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you but if you want to generate multiple objects based on `adress` maybe this helps

```js
const obj = {
  firstName: "a",
  lastName: "b",
  adresses: [{
    country: "France",
    city: "Paris"
  }, {
    country: "Italy",
    city: "Rome"
  }]
};

adressAmount = obj.adresses.length;

const adressObjects = [];

for (let i = 0; i < adressAmount; i++) {
  const {
    adresses,
    ...objWithoutAdresses
  } = obj;
  objWithoutAdresses.adress = obj.adresses[i];
  adressObjects.push(objWithoutAdresses);
}

console.log(adressObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this pretty simple and short.

```js
const data = {
  "firstName": "A",
  "lastName": "B",
  "address": [{
    "country": "France",
    "city": "Paris"
  },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Rome"
    }
  ],
};



let requiredData = data.address.map(element=>{
return {...data,address:element}
})

console.log(requiredData);
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Create an empty dictionary

2) for loop the array and store index of each array in the dictionary as value

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate the address array and create object as required

```js
let obj = {
  "firstName": "A",
  "lastName": "B",
  "address": [{
      "country": "France",
      "city": "Paris"
    },
    {
      "country": "Italy",
      "city": "Rome"
    }
  ]
}


let newData = obj.address.map(function(item) {

  return {
    firstName: obj.firstName,
    lastName: obj.lastName,
    address: {
      country: item.country,
      city: item.city
    }
  }


});
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: I think your solution is slightly better :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I want to use Ramda this is my problem